# Power law regression problem between curve_fit, python and excel

Tags: python, excel, curve-fitting

Sorry, I am new in python and stack flow. So I can not post an image.

I want to do the power law regression with curve_fit function in python. But the result is quite strange to me. I use excel to check it further. It looks big difference between these two. Black line is the result from curve_fit and the parameter of red line is from excel. Could someone let me know the difference? Thank you!

```
x=[164000,400,13000,700,57000,108,12000]
y=[0.011970,0.000098,0.066100,0.004300,0.042600,0.000061,0.002858 ]

def f(x,a,b):
    return a*x**b

popt,pocv=curve_fit(f,x,y)

ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_ylim(0.00001,0.1)
ax.set_xlim(10,1000000)

ax.scatter(x,y)

px=np.linspace(10,1000000,1000)

#parameter form curve_fit
py=a*px**b
[enter image description here][1]
#parameter from excel
pyy=3E-6*px**0.8305

ax.loglog(px,pyy,color="red")
ax.loglog(px,py,color="k")
```

Comment: python doesn't have a curve_fit function.  There is one in scipy in the optimize package - is that what you mean?  It uses the Levenburg-Marquart algorithm.  I don't know what Excel uses but if you take logarithms first and then do a linear regression on those values, you will give a different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are plotting the data in log-log space should give you a good hint to ***fit in log space***.  That is, fit `np.log(a*x**b)` to the `np.log(y)`.  A modification of your script that actually runs and gets a good fit would be:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[164000,400,13000,700,57000,108,12000]
y=[0.011970,0.000098,0.066100,0.004300,0.042600,0.000061,0.002858 ]

def f(x, a, b):
    return np.log(a*x**b)

popt,pcov=curve_fit(f, x, np.log(y), [1.e-6, 0.9])

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_ylim(0.00001,0.1)
ax.set_xlim(10,1000000)

ax.scatter(x,y)

px = np.linspace(10,1000000,1000)
a, b = popt
print("Parameters: a=%g,  b=%g" % (a, b))

#parameter form curve_fit
py=a*px**b

#parameter from excel
pyy=3e-6*px**0.8305

ax.loglog(px,pyy, color="red")
ax.loglog(px,py,  color="k")
plt.show()
```

Always be sure to provide initial values for the Parameters, and be sure to print out the results.  By way of example, running this will print out `Parameters: a=2.78612e-06,  b=0.829763` and shows both predicted lines to be nearly on top of each other.

For a better curve-fitting experience, you might find `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful (yes, I am a lead author and biased).  With `lmfit`, your fit could be:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

x=[164000,400,13000,700,57000,108,12000]
y=[0.011970,0.000098,0.066100,0.004300,0.042600,0.000061,0.002858 ]

def f(x, a, b):
    return np.log(a*x**b)

model = Model(f)
params = model.make_params(a=1.e-6, b=0.9)
result = model.fit(np.log(y), params, x=x)

print(result.fit_report())

px = np.linspace(10,1000000,1000)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.loglog(px, np.exp(result.eval(x=px)),  color="k")
plt.show()
```

Note that with lmfit, Parameters are *named*, using the names in your `f()` model function.  This will print out a fit report that includes the estimated uncertainties:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(f)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 16
    # data points      = 7
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 14.7591170
    reduced chi-square = 2.95182340
    Akaike info crit   = 9.22165592
    Bayesian info crit = 9.11347621
[[Variables]]
    a:  2.7861e-06 +/- 6.3053e-06 (226.31%) (init = 1e-06)
    b:  0.82976271 +/- 0.25700150 (30.97%) (init = 0.9)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(a, b) = -0.958
```

and produce a plot of
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Log fitting with `least_squares` is problematic, because differences between points and fitted line are increasing with bigger `x` value.  That is why fit is not as you expected. To correct this you can add bounds on parameters like below:

```
popt,pcov=curve_fit(f,x,y, bounds=(0, [3*10**(-6), 0.9]))
```

The summary parameters error you can get from `pcov`.

```
error = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))
```

**Output:**

[image]

or change fitting method.

Comment: so, it means when I want to do the regression. I always need to set the bounds, right?

Comment: @Jui-mingChang not always but in cases when you have only several data points, ant the function that you try to fit is not linear.